# Monogame/XNA - How do you resize a Texture2D and then scale it?

Tags: xna, monogame

Problem:
It seems like the Draw() call allows us to use either Destination Rectangle for resizing (5of8) or Scale (6of8/7of8) but not both.

Purpose:
I would like to resize a button from 567x634 to 400x480 and then using scale to further reduce it by 0.8 to 320x400.

Comment: Why would you want to resize a texture twice? Personally I think the Texture uploaded should have a different size itself.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is the difference when you say "resize" a texture, and "scale" it? Also I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say `(5of8)`. I'm not sure if that's something specific to XNA. Could you maybe provide more details?

Comment: @TomTsagk: It's just XNA's Draw calls.  There is a total of 8 ways fill in the parameters for SpriteBatch.Draw().  
Once you loaded in the texture, there is a draw call that takes into account the destination (that can be resized), and then there's a draw call that can scale it down to 0.9, 0.8... from the original size.  But you can't do both.

Comment: @Steven So that we can be more sloppy with the image file resolution.  The second time I scale down is just to feel like a button pressed down.
I suppose there is no easy inherent way to resize and scale via monogame, and that I had to take it to photoshop and make a couple of extra png files?

Comment: the overload 8of8 does have all of them - you just have to add "scale: 0.5f" as parameter.

And you can also just scale the rectangle on your own before sendign to Draw

Comment: @reiti.net I believe 8of8 has been deprecated and removed from functioning in Monogame. Still shows up though as an option.  When I try it, the game crashes.
Yeah, seems like photoshop is the only way left.  Still, they should have kept the draw call as it would achieve purposes 1-7 couldn't.

Comment: @spirit 8of8 should be the versino with the optional parameters (the non-optional one is deprecated I think). Have you considered, that you aso can have a transform Matrix in the Begin() Method for global scaling?
PS? With scaling the Rectangle I ment the DestinationRectangle itself, not the texture image

Answer (score 1):

You can make a RenderTarget of any width and height.
You can optional set up that render target to be persistant by sending in PreserveContents as the final parameter when you create the render target.
You can set the render target to the GraphicsDevice in the Game1.Draw method.
You can then draw your current texture to that render target with Spritebatch.Draw

SpriteBatch.Draw has a parameter that you will see by the name of 'destination'.

That rectangle should have the same size as the render target its location should be 0,0.

Once drawn to the desired new size you then have the option to use the render target as if it were a texture.

This means you can call save on it, in order to write it to file.
You can use it as a texture and draw it to the back buffer.
You can draw it with SpriteBatch.Draw using the scale parameter or by destination again.

If you made your render target persistent you can keep it around.
However this would be frowned upon by many as well as re-scaling and not pre-scaling the texture before loading. In addition this may not be supported on older hardware and on new hardware may incur a performance penalty. 
However i digress.

I believe the above answers to this part of the question generally.

> Purpose: I would like to resize a button from 567x634 to 400x480 and
>   then using scale to further reduce it

While the below is not exactly a clear question, i surmise you are asking why?

> Problem: It seems like the Draw() call allows us to use either
>   Destination Rectangle for resizing (5of8) or Scale (6of8/7of8) but not
>   both.

The act of setting a destination Rectangle means that scaling is implicit.
E.G. i have a texture of width and height 100,100 and i set it to a destination rectangle on screen of new Rectangle(0,0,80,80);
That is equivillent to performing a scaling of .8f,.8f on the width and height of the texture.  i.e. 100 *.8 = 80.

Therefor it would be first of all confusing, additionally it would be open to alternate interpretations to the operational precedence of what scaling operation happens in what order, finally it would be pointless to have both the destination and scaling parameter in the same overload.